# Limit Excel cell entry to a certain number of digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, flag

How can one fix the number of digits entered in a cell. For instance, I want only 9 digits to be entered in a cell and if it's more or less it should be flagged or not accepted. I want to make sure that junior staff don't miss digits when entering data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the data validation (Ribbon > Data > Data Validation) to control it.

Allowing a 9 digit number only, is equivalent to allowing numbers **between** 100,000,000 and 999,999,999.

---

If you want to simply **flag it** instead, you should use a conditional formatting, if the number is **not between** 100,000,000 and 999,999,999.

Answer (score -2):

**If you want to Fix the number of digits to be entered in Cell or Range of cells, You need to follow these steps:**

1. Select the Cell/ Range of Cells.
2. Click Data ribbon & hit  Data Validation.
3. Ensure you're on the Settings tab of the Data Validation dialog.
4. From the Allow drop-down click CUSTOM.
5. In the FORMULA text box enter this Formula:

   `=AND(ISNUMBER(--D76:D82),LEN(D76:D82)=9)`
6. Set INPUT & ERROR MESSAGE as you wish.
7. Finish with OK.

**Note,**

1. *Above shown Data validation allow you to enter ANY VALUE but MAXIMUM
   up to 9 Digits.*
2. If you try to enter any value is more or less than 9 Digits, Excel will show
   an error message set by you.
3. Adjust the data range in the Validation formula as your need.

**Check the Screen Shots:**

[image]

**N.B.** Just  check the Screen Shot In the first cell Excel allows to enter the value `121245789` which has 9 digits but show error message for value `5485478595` which has 10 digits.

Comment: Once again, you didn't read the question carefully and posted a non-responsive answer.  This gives the wrong result for an 8 digit number.

Comment: @fixer1234,now I've edited the Formula =9. Exactly as OP written, "I want only 9 digits to be entered in a cell and if it's more or less it should be flagged or not accepted."